# Getting Duplicate Posts on Home Page with Widget Added Between Posts

Tags: posts, widgets, homepage

I'm trying to add a widget area in between posts on the home page. I got them to show right where I want them, after the first post. The problem is that the first two posts are duplicated. The same post that shows above the new widget area is also shown after the widget area. If I take out the call for widget code and just place regular ad code then the posts don't duplicate. This only happens when I call for the widget. I'm not sure how else I could fix this.

Here's what my code looks like in index.php

```
<?php $postnum = 1; $showads = 1; $counter = 1; ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <article class="article">
        <div class="post-single post_box">
            <header>
            <div class="headline_area">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php if($options['mts_headline_meta'] == '1') { ?>
            <div class="headline_meta">
            <p class="theauthor"><?php _e('By ', 'mythemeshop'); the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
            <p class="themeta"><span class="thetime"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span><span class="thecategories"><?php the_category(' ') ?></span><span class="thecomments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php comments_number('No comments','1 Comment','% Comments'); ?></a></span></p>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
            </div><!--.headline_area-->
            </header>
            <?php if($options['mts_thumbnails'] == '1') { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('title' => '')); echo '</div>'; } ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="format_text entry-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="readmore" rel="nofollow">Read More...</a></p>
            </div>
        </div><!--.post-single-->
        </article>

        <?php if ($postnum == $showads) { ?>
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Hot-Widget") ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php } $postnum++; ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
```

If I add a normal ad code in between the two lines below, then the posts aren't duplicated but whenever I call for the widget then the posts are duplicated.

```
<?php if ($postnum == $showads) { ?>
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Hot-Widget") ) : ?>         <?php endif; ?>
<?php } $postnum++; ?>
```

Here's what my page looks like now http://carrenomedia.com/rp

Here's the link to code for the Recent/Popular posts widget
http://pastebin.com/YbMhKAMV

Comment: what is the exact code of the 'popular posts' and 'recent posts' widgets? they might contain some sort of loop code as well which will interfere with your loop.

Comment: @Michael I linked it above for you
http://pastebin.com/YbMhKAMV

Comment: Looks like it does have to do with the Recent/Popular post widget as when I removed it, there were no duplicates. I just have to figure out what code is messing it up in the widget.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the [`wp_reset_postdata();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) function after the widget area.

Probable reason for this behavior is the widget, which itself uses two `wp_query();` functions. May be those quires modifying the global `$post` data which is actually used by your main query.

I guess calling `wp_reset_postdata();` function right after the widget will solve the problem.

> ## Reference - Codex [wp_reset_postdata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)
>
> After looping through a separate query, this function restores the $post global to the current post in the main query.